# Join data from multiple columns and 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join

Those 2 are my tables I use for my data. Now when I want to join those two tables I stuck at JOIN ON golub...
I know I'm making my mistake there but I don't know what is it. Values beneath IDmajka and IDotac sometimes may be 0. That value 0 is from table "golub" and it doesn't exist. Even If I put values that exists in table "golub" it still doesn't work. It won't collect any data.
Please ignore JOIN on drzava and status cause it works.

> my query

```
SELECT * FROM popis_golubova
JOIN golub ON (golub.ID = popis_golubova.IDgolub
           AND golub.ID = popis_golubova.IDmajka 
           AND golub.ID = popis_golubova.IDotac)
JOIN drzava ON (drzava.ID=popis_golubova.IDdrzava)
JOIN status ON (status.ID=popis_golubova.IDstatus)
WHERE popis_golubova.IDkorisnik='$ID_KORISNIK'
```

> table "golub"

[image: table "golub"]

> table "popis_golubova"

[image]

Comment: In the `golub` join shouldn't all the ANDs be ORs?

Comment: tried that, doesn't work, then it makes 6 rows instead 3 when I echo it

Answer (score 0):

This is solution if it is going to help someone

```
SELECT 
O.brojgoluba AS o_brojgoluba,
M.brojgoluba AS m_brojgoluba, 
golub.spol, golub.boja, golub.rasa, golub.ime, golub.godina, golub.brojgoluba, drzava.drzava, status.status
FROM popis_golubova
JOIN drzava ON (drzava.ID=popis_golubova.IDdrzava)
JOIN status ON (status.ID=popis_golubova.IDstatus)
JOIN golub AS O ON (O.ID=popis_golubova.IDotac)
JOIN golub AS M ON (M.ID=popis_golubova.IDmajka)
JOIN golub ON (golub.ID=popis_golubova.IDgolub) 
WHERE popis_golubova.IDkorisnik='$ID_KORISNIK'
ORDER BY popis_golubova.IDgolub
```